# getting HTTPError while trying to parse info from webpage

Tags: python, request, beautifulsoup

I just started to learn Python and faced with this problem. Trued to parse price from amazon and print it to console.

This is my code:

```
import requests, bs4

def getAmazonPrice(productUrl):
    res = requests.get(productUrl)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('#addToCart > a > h5 > div > div.a-column.a-span7.a-text-right.a-span-last > span.a-size-medium.a-color-price.header-price')
    return elems[0].text.strip()


price = getAmazonPrice('http://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1460386052&sr=8-2&keywords=python+book')
print('The price is ' + price)
```

Error Message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/Code/Python/Basic/webBrowser-Module.py", line 37, in 
>       price = getAmazonPrice('[http://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1460386052&sr=8-2&keywords=python+book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275994)')
>   File "D:/Code/Python/Basic/webBrowser-Module.py", line 30, in
>   getAmazonPrice
>       res.raise_for_status()   File "C:\Python33\lib\requests\models.py", line 844, in raise_for_status
>       raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable
>   for url:
>   [http://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1460386052&sr=8-2&keywords=python+book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275994)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I get the same error message. __requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url __ even after doing as suggested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Pretending to be a real browser* by providing a `User-Agent` header would fix this particular issue:

```
res = requests.get(productUrl, headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
})
```

You would also need to tweak your CSS selector. For instance, `.header-price` would get you all of the prices on the page (non-prime and prime in this case).